# Can I freeze cinnamon buns in unbaked roll form

Tags: freezing, yeast

We’re traveling with friends and wanted to make cinnamon buns. I feel the most convenient approach would be to freeze the entire roll, then cut it while frozen when we arrive, then letting it rise. However nobody seems to take this approach when I researched the question. Typically you cut it then freeze, or parbake.

Comment: I’ve never tried, so can’t comment if it’ll work…. But I know that frozen dough is *very* hard.  It’s likely going to be very difficult to cut when frozen. You might even end up chipping bits off more than actually cutting it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can certainly freeze it in roll form, but it will be virtually impossible to cut while still frozen*. You'd need to completely thaw the roll in the refrigerator, slice, and then rise in a pan.

It would be far easier to slice and freeze. You can always reassemble the roll with the slices separated by parchment paper if you want to transport it as a roll. You can then separate them and they will thaw faster and rise more evenly.

I personally prefer to transport it as a tray (I use aluminum trays when I do this because I often make and freeze several trays at a time) so I can just pull it from the freezer and then let thaw, rise and bake. They pack more efficiently as well.

*They do this in some commercial settings, but it requires industrial power tools (usually bandsaws made for cutting through bone)

Comment: Thanks, I love the idea of cutting it then separating the slices with parchment paper. We’re traveling with bags and a dog in a car so I think we’ll need to stick it in a small cooler to protect it.

Comment: This is exactly right.  Locally, french-style croissants are sold uncooked and frozen like this - you put them on an oven tray overnight to thaw and then they rise to ~4x their frozen size, ready for baking in the morning.

Comment: You can even buy croissants sold frozen, ready to rise overnight and bake in the morning: https://www.williams-sonoma.com/products/croissant/?pkey=cgalaxy%20classic%20croissants